# zsh: no matches found when $ curl -s -X localhost:60702/api/bundle?name=light%20reading | j q '.'

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am working through the Node.js The Right Way book by Jim Wilson.  I am currently trying to use a PUSH request to create a new bundle with the specified name.
* curl -X POST http://:/api/bundle?name=

However, when I use the command: 
`$ curl -s -X POST localhost:60702/api/bundle?name=light%20reading | jq '.'`

rather than getting the JSON indicating that a Bundle has been created, I get: `zsh: no matches found: localhost:60702/api/bundle?name=light%20reading`

The command should be using a POST request to create a new All of my code is bit for bit identical to the code listed in the book.  Any ideas?

Comment: what do you get when you take off everything after the pipe (the | character)

Comment: Tried that, same `no matches found` error.  Shouldn't the -X POST flag initiate a new bundle instance rather than look for an existing one?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with this particular tutorial. It sounds like something going on inside the API and not a `zsh` related issue.

Answer (score 55):

Can you try

```
curl -s -X POST 'localhost:3000/api/bundle?name=light%20reading'
```

i.e wrap the url within '

Answer (score 24):

This seems to be an issue with zsh solved [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/31).

There are several ways to solve this:

1. You can escape the question mark **?** in the *url* by quoting the url as explained by [@huzaifa-saifuddin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56151852/2138967) to avoid zsh treating it as a wildcard character.
2. As explained [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/31#issuecomment-83036), you can create an alias for curl: `alias curl='noglob curl'`
3. As explained [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/31#issuecomment-359728582), you can disable to *nomatch* handling by adding the following to your *~/.zshrc*: `unsetopt nomatch`

Comment: It's work for me. Im MacOX 12.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

**Why?**

You need to escape the question mark,
otherwise `zsh` thinks it is a globbing or wildcard character and **tries to find files that match it** **`(that's why it says no matches found)`**.

**Solution:**
Using double or single quotes`curl 'URL_ADDRESS'` is enough:

```
curl "example.com/products?id=42"
```

In your case, try this:

```
curl -s -X POST 'localhost:60702/api/bundle?name=light%20reading' | jq '.'
```